# how to find what media I originally booted from?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I am in an installer (a linux in a ramdisk) and I want to eject the CD if it was what the BIOS originally booted from (you know, the boot order menu), is this information available somewhere in /proc ?

I'd really like to avoid relying on breadcrumbs in grub and kernel parameters if I can, so that people altering my work don't have to keep the breadcrumbs trail intact. I'm pretty sure this information is made available somewhere to the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You could identify the boot device using:

```
dmesg | grep -m1 BOOT_IMAGE
```

If root= is a UUID or /dev/[sh]d* it's probably booting from a hard disk. If it's a straight ramdisk it's probably a CD, although I'm not sure how a USB drive is represented.

Comment: what about a PXE boot, too? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I don't have a server set up to test.

Comment: it's going to be a ramdisk too, it's almost like a CD